# TextAreaFor box size is not increasing in ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to increase the text box column size in Razor but it's not working.

This is my Razor code:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.JobDescription, 
                  htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 2, @cols = 30 })
```

Below is my webpage screenshot:

[image]

But I need something like this:

[image]

which I am not getting so, can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's **Razor** - not "rozar" or anything else you've used ....

Answer (score 0):

You dont need @ with every html attr @ is used here with class to escape the c# class    try

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.JobDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control",rows = "2",cols = "30" })
```

Comment: Hi Rahul its not giving the required output after implementing your code.